# error building nutch 2.1 on windows 7 Could not load definitions from resource org/sonar/ant/antlib.xml

Tags: ant, nutch

When I try to build nutch 2.1 on my windows 7 machine i get the below error:

```
Buildfile: C:\apache-nutch-2.1\build.xml
  [taskdef] Could not load definitions from resource org/sonar/ant/antlib.xml. It could not be found.
ivy-probe-antlib:
ivy-download:
  [taskdef] Could not load definitions from resource org/sonar/ant/antlib.xml. It could not be found.
ivy-download-unchecked:
ivy-init-antlib:
ivy-init:
init:

resolve-default:
[ivy:resolve] :: Ivy 2.2.0 - 20100923230623 :: http://ant.apache.org/ivy/ ::
[ivy:resolve] :: loading settings :: file = C:\apache-nutch-2.1\ivy\ivysettings.xml
  [taskdef] Could not load definitions from resource org/sonar/ant/antlib.xml. It could not be found.

copy-libs:

compile-core:
     C:\apache-nutch-2.1\build.xml:97: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
     Compiling 181 source files to C:\apache-nutch-2.1\build\classes
     warning: [path] bad path element "C:\apache-nutch-2.1\build\lib\activation.jar": no such file or directory
     warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.6
     C:\apache-nutch-2.1\src\java\org\apache\nutch\api\APIInfoResource.java:23: error: package org.restlet.resource does not exist
     import org.restlet.resource.Get;
                                ^
     C:\apache-nutch-2.1\src\java\org\apache\nutch\api\APIInfoResource.java:24: error: package org.restlet.resource does not exist
     import org.restlet.resource.ServerResource;
                                ^
     C:\apache-nutch-2.1\src\java\org\apache\nutch\api\APIInfoResource.java:26: error: cannot find symbol
     public class APIInfoResource extends ServerResource {
                                          ^
       symbol: class ServerResource
     C:\apache-nutch-2.1\src\java\org\apache\nutch\api\AdminResource.java:23: error: package org.restlet.resource does not exist
     import org.restlet.resource.Get;
                                ^
     C:\apache-nutch-2.1\src\java\org\apache\nutch\api\AdminResource.java:24: error: package org.restlet.resource does not exist
     import org.restlet.resource.ServerResource;
                                ^
     C:\apache-nutch-2.1\src\java\org\apache\nutch\api\AdminResource.java:28: error: cannot find symbol
     public class AdminResource extends ServerResource {
                                        ^
       symbol: class ServerResource
     C:\apache-nutch-2.1\src\java\org\apache\nutch\api\ConfResource.java:22: error: package org.restlet.data does not exist
     import org.restlet.data.Form;
                            ^
     C:\apache-nutch-2.1\src\java\org\apache\nutch\api\ConfResource.java:23: error: package org.restlet.resource does not exist
     import org.restlet.resource.Delete;
                                ^
     C:\apache-nutch-2.1\src\java\org\apache\nutch\api\ConfResource.java:24: error: package org.restlet.resource does not exist
     import org.restlet.resource.Get;
                                ^
     C:\apache-nutch-2.1\src\java\org\apache\nutch\api\ConfResource.java:25: error: package org.restlet.resource does not exist
     import org.restlet.resource.Post;
                                ^
     C:\apache-nutch-2.1\src\java\org\apache\nutch\api\ConfResource.java:26: error: package org.restlet.resource does not exist
     import org.restlet.resource.Put;
                                ^
     C:\apache-nutch-2.1\src\java\org\apache\nutch\api\ConfResource.java:27: error: package org.restlet.resource does not exist
     import org.restlet.resource.ServerResource;
                                ^
     C:\apache-nutch-2.1\src\java\org\apache\nutch\api\ConfResource.java:29: error: cannot find symbol
     public class ConfResource extends ServerResource {
                                       ^
       symbol: class ServerResource
     C:\apache-nutch-2.1\src\java\org\apache\nutch\api\DbReader.java:29: error: package org.apache.avro.util does not exist
     import org.apache.avro.util.Utf8;
                                ^
     C:\apache-nutch-2.1\src\java\org\apache\nutch\api\DbReader.java:30: error: package org.apache.gora.query does not exist
     import org.apache.gora.query.Query;
                                 ^
     C:\apache-nutch-2.1\src\java\org\apache\nutch\api\DbReader.java:31: error: package org.apache.gora.query does not exist
     import org.apache.gora.query.Result;
                                 ^
     C:\apache-nutch-2.1\src\java\org\apache\nutch\api\DbReader.java:32: error: package org.apache.gora.store does not exist
     import org.apache.gora.store.DataStore;
                                 ^
     C:\apache-nutch-2.1\src\java\org\apache\nutch\api\DbReader.java:52: error: cannot find symbol
       DataStore<String,WebPage> store;
       ^
       symbol:   class DataStore
       location: class DbReader
     C:\apache-nutch-2.1\src\java\org\apache\nutch\storage\WebPage.java:22: error: package org.apache.avro does not exist
     import org.apache.avro.Protocol;
                           ^
     C:\apache-nutch-2.1\src\java\org\apache\nutch\storage\WebPage.java:23: error: package org.apache.avro does not exist
     import org.apache.avro.Schema;
                           ^
     C:\apache-nutch-2.1\src\java\org\apache\nutch\storage\WebPage.java:24: error: package org.apache.avro does not exist
     import org.apache.avro.AvroRuntimeException;
                           ^
     C:\apache-nutch-2.1\src\java\org\apache\nutch\storage\WebPage.java:25: error: package org.apache.avro does not exist
     import org.apache.avro.Protocol;
                           ^
     C:\apache-nutch-2.1\src\java\org\apache\nutch\storage\WebPage.java:26: error: package org.apache.avro.util does not exist
     import org.apache.avro.util.Utf8;
                                ^
     C:\apache-nutch-2.1\src\java\org\apache\nutch\storage\WebPage.java:27: error: package org.apache.avro.ipc does not exist
     import org.apache.avro.ipc.AvroRemoteException;
                               ^
     C:\apache-nutch-2.1\src\java\org\apache\nutch\storage\WebPage.java:28: error: package org.apache.avro.generic does not exist
     import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericArray;
                                   ^
     C:\apache-nutch-2.1\src\java\org\apache\nutch\storage\WebPage.java:29: error: package org.apache.avro.specific does not exist
     import org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificExceptionBase;
                                    ^
     C:\apache-nutch-2.1\src\java\org\apache\nutch\storage\WebPage.java:30: error: package org.apache.avro.specific does not exist
     import org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificRecordBase;
                                    ^
     C:\apache-nutch-2.1\src\java\org\apache\nutch\storage\WebPage.java:31: error: package org.apache.avro.specific does not exist
     import org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificRecord;
                                    ^
     C:\apache-nutch-2.1\src\java\org\apache\nutch\storage\WebPage.java:32: error: package org.apache.avro.specific does not exist
     import org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificFixed;
                                    ^
     C:\apache-nutch-2.1\src\java\org\apache\nutch\storage\WebPage.java:33: error: package org.apache.gora.persistency does not exist
     import org.apache.gora.persistency.StateManager;
                                       ^
     C:\apache-nutch-2.1\src\java\org\apache\nutch\storage\WebPage.java:34: error: package org.apache.gora.persistency.impl does not exist
     import org.apache.gora.persistency.impl.PersistentBase;
                                            ^
     C:\apache-nutch-2.1\src\java\org\apache\nutch\storage\WebPage.java:35: error: package org.apache.gora.persistency.impl does not exist
     import org.apache.gora.persistency.impl.StateManagerImpl;
                                            ^
     C:\apache-nutch-2.1\src\java\org\apache\nutch\storage\WebPage.java:36: error: package org.apache.gora.persistency does not exist
     import org.apache.gora.persistency.StatefulHashMap;
                                       ^
     C:\apache-nutch-2.1\src\java\org\apache\nutch\storage\WebPage.java:37: error: package org.apache.gora.persistency does not exist
     import org.apache.gora.persistency.ListGenericArray;
                                       ^
     C:\apache-nutch-2.1\src\java\org\apache\nutch\storage\WebPage.java:40: error: cannot find symbol
     public class WebPage extends PersistentBase {
                                  ^
       symbol: class PersistentBase
     C:\apache-nutch-2.1\src\java\org\apache\nutch\storage\WebPage.java:41: error: cannot find symbol
       public static final Schema _SCHEMA = Schema.parse("{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"WebPage\",\"namespace\":\"org.apache.nutch.storage\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"baseUrl\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"status\",\"type\":\"int\"},{\"name\":\"fetchTime\",\"type\":\"long\"},{\"name\":\"prevFetchTime\",\"type\":\"long\"},{\"name\":\"fetchInterval\",\"type\":\"int\"},{\"name\":\"retriesSinceFetch\",\"type\":\"int\"},{\"name\":\"modifiedTime\",\"type\":\"long\"},{\"name\":\"protocolStatus\",\"type\":{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"ProtocolStatus\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"code\",\"type\":\"int\"},{\"name\":\"args\",\"type\":{\"type\":\"array\",\"items\":\"string\"}},{\"name\":\"lastModified\",\"type\":\"long\"}]}},{\"name\":\"content\",\"type\":\"bytes\"},{\"name\":\"contentType\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"prevSignature\",\"type\":\"bytes\"},{\"name\":\"signature\",\"type\":\"bytes\"},{\"name\":\"title\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"text\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"parseStatus\",\"type\":{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"ParseStatus\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"majorCode\",\"type\":\"int\"},{\"name\":\"minorCode\",\"type\":\"int\"},{\"name\":\"args\",\"type\":{\"type\":\"array\",\"items\":\"string\"}}]}},{\"name\":\"score\",\"type\":\"float\"},{\"name\":\"reprUrl\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"headers\",\"type\":{\"type\":\"map\",\"values\":\"string\"}},{\"name\":\"outlinks\",\"type\":{\"type\":\"map\",\"values\":\"string\"}},{\"name\":\"inlinks\",\"type\":{\"type\":\"map\",\"values\":\"string\"}},{\"name\":\"markers\",\"type\":{\"type\":\"map\",\"values\":\"string\"}},{\"name\":\"metadata\",\"type\":{\"type\":\"map\",\"values\":\"bytes\"}}]}");
                           ^
       symbol:   class Schema
       location: class WebPage
     C:\apache-nutch-2.1\src\java\org\apache\nutch\storage\WebPage.java:77: error: cannot find symbol
       private Utf8 baseUrl;
               ^
       symbol:   class Utf8
       location: class WebPage
     C:\apache-nutch-2.1\src\java\org\apache\nutch\storage\ProtocolStatus.java:22: error: package org.apache.avro does not exist
     import org.apache.avro.Protocol;
                           ^
     C:\apache-nutch-2.1\src\java\org\apache\nutch\storage\ProtocolStatus.java:23: error: package org.apache.avro does not exist
     import org.apache.avro.Schema;
                           ^
     C:\apache-nutch-2.1\src\java\org\apache\nutch\storage\ProtocolStatus.java:24: error: package org.apache.avro does not exist
     import org.apache.avro.AvroRuntimeException;
                           ^
     C:\apache-nutch-2.1\src\java\org\apache\nutch\storage\ProtocolStatus.java:25: error: package org.apache.avro does not exist
     import org.apache.avro.Protocol;
                           ^
     C:\apache-nutch-2.1\src\java\org\apache\nutch\storage\ProtocolStatus.java:26: error: package org.apache.avro.util does not exist
     import org.apache.avro.util.Utf8;
                                ^
     C:\apache-nutch-2.1\src\java\org\apache\nutch\storage\ProtocolStatus.java:27: error: package org.apache.avro.ipc does not exist
     import org.apache.avro.ipc.AvroRemoteException;
                               ^
     C:\apache-nutch-2.1\src\java\org\apache\nutch\storage\ProtocolStatus.java:28: error: package org.apache.avro.generic does not exist
     import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericArray;
                                   ^
     C:\apache-nutch-2.1\src\java\org\apache\nutch\storage\ProtocolStatus.java:29: error: package org.apache.avro.specific does not exist
     import org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificExceptionBase;
                                    ^
     C:\apache-nutch-2.1\src\java\org\apache\nutch\storage\ProtocolStatus.java:30: error: package org.apache.avro.specific does not exist
     import org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificRecordBase;
                                    ^
     C:\apache-nutch-2.1\src\java\org\apache\nutch\storage\ProtocolStatus.java:31: error: package org.apache.avro.specific does not exist
     import org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificRecord;
                                    ^
     C:\apache-nutch-2.1\src\java\org\apache\nutch\storage\ProtocolStatus.java:32: error: package org.apache.avro.specific does not exist
     import org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificFixed;
                                    ^
     C:\apache-nutch-2.1\src\java\org\apache\nutch\storage\ProtocolStatus.java:33: error: package org.apache.gora.persistency does not exist
     import org.apache.gora.persistency.StateManager;
                                       ^
     C:\apache-nutch-2.1\src\java\org\apache\nutch\storage\ProtocolStatus.java:34: error: package org.apache.gora.persistency.impl does not exist
     import org.apache.gora.persistency.impl.PersistentBase;
                                            ^
     C:\apache-nutch-2.1\src\java\org\apache\nutch\storage\ProtocolStatus.java:35: error: package org.apache.gora.persistency.impl does not exist
     import org.apache.gora.persistency.impl.StateManagerImpl;
                                            ^
     C:\apache-nutch-2.1\src\java\org\apache\nutch\storage\ProtocolStatus.java:36: error: package org.apache.gora.persistency does not exist
     import org.apache.gora.persistency.StatefulHashMap;
                                       ^
     C:\apache-nutch-2.1\src\java\org\apache\nutch\storage\ProtocolStatus.java:37: error: package org.apache.gora.persistency does not exist
     import org.apache.gora.persistency.ListGenericArray;
                                       ^
     C:\apache-nutch-2.1\src\java\org\apache\nutch\storage\ProtocolStatus.java:40: error: cannot find symbol
     public class ProtocolStatus extends PersistentBase {
                                         ^
       symbol: class PersistentBase
     C:\apache-nutch-2.1\src\java\org\apache\nutch\storage\WebPage.java:86: error: cannot find symbol
       private Utf8 contentType;
               ^
       symbol:   class Utf8
       location: class WebPage
     C:\apache-nutch-2.1\src\java\org\apache\nutch\storage\WebPage.java:89: error: cannot find symbol
       private Utf8 title;
               ^
       symbol:   class Utf8
       location: class WebPage
     C:\apache-nutch-2.1\src\java\org\apache\nutch\storage\WebPage.java:90: error: cannot find symbol
       private Utf8 text;
               ^
       symbol:   class Utf8
       location: class WebPage
     C:\apache-nutch-2.1\src\java\org\apache\nutch\storage\ParseStatus.java:22: error: package org.apache.avro does not exist
     import org.apache.avro.Protocol;
                           ^
     C:\apache-nutch-2.1\src\java\org\apache\nutch\storage\ParseStatus.java:23: error: package org.apache.avro does not exist
     import org.apache.avro.Schema;
                           ^
     C:\apache-nutch-2.1\src\java\org\apache\nutch\storage\ParseStatus.java:24: error: package org.apache.avro does not exist
     import org.apache.avro.AvroRuntimeException;
                           ^
     C:\apache-nutch-2.1\src\java\org\apache\nutch\storage\ParseStatus.java:25: error: package org.apache.avro does not exist
     import org.apache.avro.Protocol;
                           ^
     C:\apache-nutch-2.1\src\java\org\apache\nutch\storage\ParseStatus.java:26: error: package org.apache.avro.util does not exist
     import org.apache.avro.util.Utf8;
                                ^
     C:\apache-nutch-2.1\src\java\org\apache\nutch\storage\ParseStatus.java:27: error: package org.apache.avro.ipc does not exist
     import org.apache.avro.ipc.AvroRemoteException;
                               ^
     C:\apache-nutch-2.1\src\java\org\apache\nutch\storage\ParseStatus.java:28: error: package org.apache.avro.generic does not exist
     import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericArray;
                                   ^
     C:\apache-nutch-2.1\src\java\org\apache\nutch\storage\ParseStatus.java:29: error: package org.apache.avro.specific does not exist
     import org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificExceptionBase;
                                    ^
     C:\apache-nutch-2.1\src\java\org\apache\nutch\storage\ParseStatus.java:30: error: package org.apache.avro.specific does not exist
     import org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificRecordBase;
                                    ^
     C:\apache-nutch-2.1\src\java\org\apache\nutch\storage\ParseStatus.java:31: error: package org.apache.avro.specific does not exist
     import org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificRecord;
                                    ^
     C:\apache-nutch-2.1\src\java\org\apache\nutch\storage\ParseStatus.java:32: error: package org.apache.avro.specific does not exist
     import org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificFixed;
                                    ^
     C:\apache-nutch-2.1\src\java\org\apache\nutch\storage\ParseStatus.java:33: error: package org.apache.gora.persistency does not exist
     import org.apache.gora.persistency.StateManager;
                                       ^
     C:\apache-nutch-2.1\src\java\org\apache\nutch\storage\ParseStatus.java:34: error: package org.apache.gora.persistency.impl does not exist
     import org.apache.gora.persistency.impl.PersistentBase;
                                            ^
     C:\apache-nutch-2.1\src\java\org\apache\nutch\storage\ParseStatus.java:35: error: package org.apache.gora.persistency.impl does not exist
     import org.apache.gora.persistency.impl.StateManagerImpl;
                                            ^
     C:\apache-nutch-2.1\src\java\org\apache\nutch\storage\ParseStatus.java:36: error: package org.apache.gora.persistency does not exist
     import org.apache.gora.persistency.StatefulHashMap;
                                       ^
     C:\apache-nutch-2.1\src\java\org\apache\nutch\storage\ParseStatus.java:37: error: package org.apache.gora.persistency does not exist
     import org.apache.gora.persistency.ListGenericArray;
                                       ^
     C:\apache-nutch-2.1\src\java\org\apache\nutch\storage\ParseStatus.java:40: error: cannot find symbol
     public class ParseStatus extends PersistentBase {
                                      ^
       symbol: class PersistentBase
     C:\apache-nutch-2.1\src\java\org\apache\nutch\storage\WebPage.java:93: error: cannot find symbol
       private Utf8 reprUrl;
               ^
       symbol:   class Utf8
       location: class WebPage
     C:\apache-nutch-2.1\src\java\org\apache\nutch\storage\WebPage.java:94: error: cannot find symbol
       private Map<Utf8,Utf8> headers;
                   ^
       symbol:   class Utf8
       location: class WebPage
     C:\apache-nutch-2.1\src\java\org\apache\nutch\storage\WebPage.java:94: error: cannot find symbol
       private Map<Utf8,Utf8> headers;
                        ^
       symbol:   class Utf8
       location: class WebPage
     C:\apache-nutch-2.1\src\java\org\apache\nutch\storage\WebPage.java:95: error: cannot find symbol
       private Map<Utf8,Utf8> outlinks;
                   ^
       symbol:   class Utf8
       location: class WebPage
     C:\apache-nutch-2.1\src\java\org\apache\nutch\storage\WebPage.java:95: error: cannot find symbol
       private Map<Utf8,Utf8> outlinks;
                        ^
       symbol:   class Utf8
       location: class WebPage
     C:\apache-nutch-2.1\src\java\org\apache\nutch\storage\WebPage.java:96: error: cannot find symbol
       private Map<Utf8,Utf8> inlinks;
                   ^
       symbol:   class Utf8
       location: class WebPage
     C:\apache-nutch-2.1\src\java\org\apache\nutch\storage\WebPage.java:96: error: cannot find symbol
       private Map<Utf8,Utf8> inlinks;
                        ^
       symbol:   class Utf8
       location: class WebPage
     C:\apache-nutch-2.1\src\java\org\apache\nutch\storage\WebPage.java:97: error: cannot find symbol
       private Map<Utf8,Utf8> markers;
                   ^
       symbol:   class Utf8
       location: class WebPage
     C:\apache-nutch-2.1\src\java\org\apache\nutch\storage\WebPage.java:97: error: cannot find symbol
       private Map<Utf8,Utf8> markers;
                        ^
       symbol:   class Utf8
       location: class WebPage
     C:\apache-nutch-2.1\src\java\org\apache\nutch\storage\WebPage.java:98: error: cannot find symbol
       private Map<Utf8,ByteBuffer> metadata;
                   ^
       symbol:   class Utf8
       location: class WebPage
     C:\apache-nutch-2.1\src\java\org\apache\nutch\storage\WebPage.java:102: error: cannot find symbol
       public WebPage(StateManager stateManager) {
                      ^
       symbol:   class StateManager
       location: class WebPage
     C:\apache-nutch-2.1\src\java\org\apache\nutch\storage\WebPage.java:110: error: cannot find symbol
       public WebPage newInstance(StateManager stateManager) {
                                  ^
       symbol:   class StateManager
       location: class WebPage
     C:\apache-nutch-2.1\src\java\org\apache\nutch\storage\WebPage.java:113: error: cannot find symbol
       public Schema getSchema() { return _SCHEMA; }
              ^
       symbol:   class Schema
       location: class WebPage
     C:\apache-nutch-2.1\src\java\org\apache\nutch\storage\WebPage.java:171: error: cannot find symbol
       public Utf8 getBaseUrl() {
              ^
       symbol:   class Utf8
       location: class WebPage
     C:\apache-nutch-2.1\src\java\org\apache\nutch\storage\WebPage.java:174: error: cannot find symbol
       public void setBaseUrl(Utf8 value) {
                              ^
       symbol:   class Utf8
       location: class WebPage
     C:\apache-nutch-2.1\src\java\org\apache\nutch\storage\WebPage.java:225: error: cannot find symbol
       public Utf8 getContentType() {
              ^
       symbol:   class Utf8
       location: class WebPage
     C:\apache-nutch-2.1\src\java\org\apache\nutch\storage\WebPage.java:228: error: cannot find symbol
       public void setContentType(Utf8 value) {
                                  ^
       symbol:   class Utf8
       location: class WebPage
     C:\apache-nutch-2.1\src\java\org\apache\nutch\storage\WebPage.java:243: error: cannot find symbol
       public Utf8 getTitle() {
              ^
       symbol:   class Utf8
       location: class WebPage
     C:\apache-nutch-2.1\src\java\org\apache\nutch\storage\WebPage.java:246: error: cannot find symbol
       public void setTitle(Utf8 value) {
                            ^
       symbol:   class Utf8
       location: class WebPage
     C:\apache-nutch-2.1\src\java\org\apache\nutch\storage\WebPage.java:249: error: cannot find symbol
       public Utf8 getText() {
              ^
       symbol:   class Utf8
       location: class WebPage
     C:\apache-nutch-2.1\src\java\org\apache\nutch\storage\WebPage.java:252: error: cannot find symbol
       public void setText(Utf8 value) {
                           ^
       symbol:   class Utf8
       location: class WebPage
     C:\apache-nutch-2.1\src\java\org\apache\nutch\storage\WebPage.java:267: error: cannot find symbol
       public Utf8 getReprUrl() {
              ^
       symbol:   class Utf8
       location: class WebPage
     C:\apache-nutch-2.1\src\java\org\apache\nutch\storage\WebPage.java:270: error: cannot find symbol
       public void setReprUrl(Utf8 value) {
                              ^
       symbol:   class Utf8
       location: class WebPage
     C:\apache-nutch-2.1\src\java\org\apache\nutch\storage\WebPage.java:273: error: cannot find symbol
       public Map<Utf8, Utf8> getHeaders() {
                  ^
       symbol:   class Utf8
       location: class WebPage
     C:\apache-nutch-2.1\src\java\org\apache\nutch\storage\WebPage.java:273: error: cannot find symbol
       public Map<Utf8, Utf8> getHeaders() {
                        ^
       symbol:   class Utf8
       location: class WebPage
     C:\apache-nutch-2.1\src\java\org\apache\nutch\storage\WebPage.java:276: error: cannot find symbol
       public Utf8 getFromHeaders(Utf8 key) {
                                  ^
       symbol:   class Utf8
       location: class WebPage
     C:\apache-nutch-2.1\src\java\org\apache\nutch\indexer\mongodb\MongodbIndexer.java:18: warning: [deprecation] JobConf in org.apache.hadoop.mapred has been deprecated
     import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf;
                                    ^
     C:\apache-nutch-2.1\src\java\org\apache\nutch\indexer\mongodb\MongodbWriter.java:7: warning: [deprecation] JobConf in org.apache.hadoop.mapred has been deprecated
     import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf;
                                    ^
     C:\apache-nutch-2.1\src\java\org\apache\nutch\tools\arc\ArcInputFormat.java:23: warning: [deprecation] FileInputFormat in org.apache.hadoop.mapred has been deprecated
     import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat;
                                    ^
     C:\apache-nutch-2.1\src\java\org\apache\nutch\tools\arc\ArcInputFormat.java:24: warning: [deprecation] FileSplit in org.apache.hadoop.mapred has been deprecated
     import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileSplit;
                                    ^
     ..
     ..
```

more errors are there ..........

```
 C:\apache-nutch-2.1\src\java\org\apache\nutch\util\SuffixStringMatcher.java:46: warning: [rawtypes] found raw type: Iterator
     Iterator iter= suffixes.iterator();
     ^
   missing type arguments for generic class Iterator<E>
   where E is a type-variable:
     E extends Object declared in interface Iterator
 C:\apache-nutch-2.1\src\java\org\apache\nutch\util\ToolUtil.java:48: warning: [unchecked] unchecked cast
     Map<String,Object> jobs = (Map<String,Object>)results.get(Nutch.STAT_JOBS);
                                                              ^
   required: Map<String,Object>
   found:    Object
 100 errors
 69 warnings
```

How can I fix this and get Nutch running?

Comment: Just looking at the error stacktrace tells me your build is missing it's 3rd party dependency jars. Requires more analysis. Have you reported the problem to the Nutch developers?

Comment: Yes i have reported the error to the nutch developers hopefully will get a response from them soon.

Comment: I had a quick look at the build logic. They're using ivy to download the 3rd party dependencies. If this failed, it would explain your subsequent errors. The ivy configuration is a bit convoluted (lots of references to external files). I gave up.... http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/nutch/trunk/

Comment: I have the same issue on Ubuntu with Intellij IDEA

Comment: I spent nearly 4 hours yesterday following http://nlp.solutions.asia/?p=180
Tutorial. I later found out that there was some long winded explanation about cygwin's dependencies and how you would have to spend half a day dinking with that. Use vmware and a ubuntu distro , I had it working in 2 hours.

Answer (score 0):

For those desperate Googlers who find this:

I had a similar issue which I was able to troubleshoot by adding -v (verbose) to my ant command.  With that, I could see that it was a cygwin/windows path issue that was actually causing the problem.  Reluctantly, I opened a cmd.exe prompt, set the appropriate environment variables, and it worked fine.